# 3gp to wav file Android

Tags: java, android, audio

i want to convert 3gp file to wave file can i do it programmatically . As the headers are different is it possible .Any help would be appreciated 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/).

Comment: ffmpeg also generates the 3gp file not the wave file internally the header contains the 3gp not the RIFF WAVE format .